# HTML TIDY not indenting inline tags and script tags properly

Tags: html, htmltidy

I am trying to use [HTMLTIDY](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html) for indenting my html file. I am using the command line version of it.

```
tidy --doctype html5 --tidy-mark no --indent auto --indent-spaces 4 --wrap 0 --write-back yes --output-html yes --drop-empty-elements no filename.html
```

Its indenting everything properly except the script tags and inline elements are coming in the same line instead of indenting.

**Before:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>
<title>sometitle</title>
</head><body><div class="test"><a href="#">testlink1</a><a href="#">testlink1</a><a href="#">testlink1</a></div></body>
</html>
```

**after:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="something.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="something.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="something.js">
</script>

    <title>sometitle</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="test">
        <a href="#">testlink1</a><a href="#">testlink1</a><a href="#">testlink1</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to figure out any options as per the documention to fix it. please help me solving this.

Comment: For inline tags, whitespace characters are meaningful. The parser has no right to insert whitespaces between parts of inline context, the same way as it can't insert them between the letters of a word. If you need whitespaces between links, you have to put them into the original file, so Tidy will be able to convert them into line breaks with indentation.

Comment: that's fine with inline elements. what about the script tags any help

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I was having this issue myself and it appears to be a [known bug with HTML Tidy](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/issues/56) which the devs don't care enough to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**balthisar** commented](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/56#issuecomment-72358398) on 1 Feb:

> Fixed in develop-500. Please feel free to re-open this if you still
>   have a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea where to find a windows binary for this?  Or, better yet, a DLL build, for Notepad++?

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\Tidy2.dll`

Comment: @DaveBurton Notepad++, Plugins, Plugin Manager

Comment: Thanks, Cees, but that version (Tidy2 version 0.2) has the script tag formatting bug.